# How to add a job to the down/upstream of another jenkinsjob in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

currently I try to automize my Jenkins-buildchain.
I wrote a groovy-script that copies my jobs, changes the Labels, SVN etc. everything works so far.

the only thing missing now is changing the downstream of the Job. Here is what i got so far:

```
oldVersion="3.1"
newVersion="4.0"

view = Hudson.instance.getView("myviewName");
for (item in newView.getItems()){
  println(item.getName()); 

  ArrayList down = item.getDownstreamProjects();
  if (down != null){
    for (downjob in down){
      println("\t"+downjob.getName());
      replaceJob=newView.getItem(downjob.getName().replace(oldVersion,newVersion));
      println("\t"+replaceJob.getName());
      //here I want to add the new version of the job and remove the old one
    }
  }
}
```

I get the wanted jobs but can't persist them in the exitsting Project
neither something like

```
item.addToList(replaceJob, down)
```

or

```
item.getDownstreamProjects().add(replaceJob)
```

seem so work, it seems like I am getting something totally wrong and the list is not the reference but a copy of the List. In addition both commands above are doing nothing, and are not creating any exceptions or errors

PS.: I'm new to Groovy and this whole Jenkins scripting, so please be gentle if I'm missing something obvious.